# Too many commas in name: Using Jabref and Texmaker

Tags: citing, natbib, texmaker, jabref

I'm using the natbib package in Latex with the \bibliographystyle{apalike}. I'm getting errors from my citations and it's due to how I'm listing the authors. The error I'm getting is "Too many commas in name 1 of..." with any citation with three or more authors causing problems.

In my author list, I am separating all authors using the "\&" command. The .bbl file looks like (for one that is causing problems):

```
\bibitem[Chella, 2012]{Chella2012}
**Chella, M. A. \&~Torum, A. . M.~D. (2012).**
\newblock An overview of wave impact forces on offshore wind turbine
  substructures.
\newblock {\em Energy Procedia}, 20:217--226.
```

How would I enter all of the author names without causing this problem? The second line seems to be causing the problem. (With stars on it)

Second question: I want to have the citations appear as [Last name, year]. I thought I needed to use \citep{} for this but it still just brings up the number. Any ideas on what I need to include in my \usepackage[?]{natbib} call? Assuming this is where the problem is.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you show the entry in the `.bib` file?

Comment: Ok actually I worked out the first problem: I have "&" separating the author names rather than "and". This fixed the bibliography.

Comment: You have to say `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`

Answer (score 5):

The correct entry in the bib file should be

```
@article{chella2012overview,
  title={An overview of wave impact forces on offshore wind turbine substructures},
  author={Chella, Mayilvahanan Alagan and T{\o}rum, Alf and Myrhaug, Dag},
  journal={Energy Procedia},
  volume={20},
  pages={217--226},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Note that the *keyword* `and` separates different authors; the bib style will split the field into components and output them in the correct way.